# Vim does not call functions correctly when wrapped in another function

Tags: vimscript, signs

Please consider these 3 small functions:

```
" place sign >> at line 10
function PlaceSign()
  call sign_define('a', {'text': '>>', 'texthl': 'LineNr'})
  call sign_place(10, 'g1', 'a', expand('%'), {'lnum' : 10})
endfunction

" echo the character typed by the user and clear sign
function EchoChar()
  let l:c = nr2char(getchar())
  echo l:c
  call sign_unplace('g1')
endfunction

" run both functions above one after the other
function PlaceEcho()
  call PlaceSign()
  call EchoChar()
endfunction
```

- If I run `:call PlaceSign()` the result is as expected, it places sign '>>' at line 10
- If I run `:call EchoChar()` it waits for the user input, then it echoes, and then clears sign

Now the problem:

- If I run `:call PlaceEcho()` it waits for the user input, then it echoes, **without running `PlaceSign()` first** and I cannot understand why. The expected result would be: place sign at line 10, echo user typed character, clear sign. No idea why this is not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't like updating Screen too often.

```
function PlaceEcho()
    call PlaceSign()
    redraw
    "^^^^^
    call EchoChar()
endfunction
```

Comment: Yup, that was it, thank you!