# Automatically highlight visual selection matches

Tags: vimscript, neovim, visual-mode, functions

Since there are no VisualEnter and VisualLeave events, I am trying to make a function that will activate on every cursor movement in visual mode, i.e. it will automatically highlight all the matches of the current visual selection.

The mapping from [Automatically highlight all occurrences of the selected text in visual mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20077/automatically-highlight-all-occurrences-of-the-selected-text-in-visual-mode):

```
xnoremap <silent> <cr> "*y:silent! let searchTerm = '\V'.substitute(escape(@*, '\/'), "\n", '\\n', "g") <bar> let @/ = searchTerm <bar> echo '/'.@/ <bar> call histadd("search", searchTerm) <bar> set hls<cr>
```

works perfectly for me but I am failing to implement it into function. This is what I tried:

```
function! HighlightVisual(mode)
    if mode()=~#"^[vV\<C-v>]"
        call feedkeys('"*y')
        let searchTerm = '\V'.substitute(escape(@*, '\/'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
        let @/ = searchTerm
        echo '/'.@/
        call histadd("search", searchTerm)
        set hls
    endif
endfunction

autocmd CursorMoved * call HighlightVisual(mode())
```

However, it is not working.
What am I doing wrong? Moreover, does anybody think there is a better way to search for matches on every cursor movement in visual mode?

Comment: Part of the problem you're running into might be that the `@/` register is restored at the end of a function call. See [`:help function-search-undo`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#function-search-undo) for more details. As a workaround, you can `return searchTerm` from your function and use an `autocmd CursorMoved * let @/ = HighlightVisual(mode())` instead (though you might need to handle the case where you're not in Visual mode to prevent clobbering that register in that case.)

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work. Firstly, I found from [Vim does not call functions correctly when wrapped in another function](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28404/vim-does-not-call-functions-correctly-when-wrapped-in-another-function) that "Vim doesn't like updating Screen too often" so `redraw` was necessary after `set hls`. And secondly, `y` was forcing normal mode and `gv` was moving cursor triggering the `autocmd CursorMoved` inside the function thus making an infinite loop. I made a workaround by `set eventignore=CursorMoved` and resetting it back at the end of function. I am saving selected word to register h (as in highlight) but you can choose any by changing `"hy` and `@h`. Moreover, I added highlight toggle when not needed. So, if somebody wants to use the feature of automatically highlighting visual matches, here is the code:

```
function! HighlightVisual(mode)
    if mode()=~#"^[vV\<C-v>]"
        set eventignore=CursorMoved
        normal "hy
        normal gv
        let searchTerm = '\V'.substitute(escape(@h, '\/'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
        let @/ = searchTerm
        call histadd("search", searchTerm)
        set hls
        redraw
        set eventignore=""
    endif
endfunction

autocmd CursorMoved * :call HighlightVisual(mode())
vnoremap <silent> <ESC> :<C-u>set nohlsearch<CR>
```

; just copy-paste it in your .vimrc/init.vim.
Big thanks to [trusktr](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/5626/trusktr) as I  used his answer in [Automatically highlight all occurrences of the selected text in visual mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20077/automatically-highlight-all-occurrences-of-the-selected-text-in-visual-mode) to build my function I wanted for sooo long.
Happy coding!